# How to Keep a Beep sound Playing till Msgbox is closed

Tags: excel, vba

How to make the Beep Sound start, and Continue repeating till the MsgBox is Closed in VBA Excel?
Assume that We have This Code for Example

```
            Dim i As Integer
            For i = 1 To 10
                Dim frequency As Long, duration As Long
                frequency = 1000
                duration = 100
                APIBeep frequency, duration
            Next i
            Style = vbCritical + vbOKOnly + vbMsgBoxHelpButton + vbDefaultButton2
            resp = MsgBox("This Barcode is INVALID Please Try Again", Style, "Invalid Barcode"):
```

Comment: You would need to create a custom UserForm to display the message: you can play the sound using code in the form.

Comment: Would application.ontime still work, if not declaring the msgbox modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Do While Msgbox "Invalid text found  . . . . . "

Loop
```

Have not tested it though.

Userform could be the way

```
 Do While SomeUserForm.show 

 `Cant think of the correct time script now and Im not at my pc`

 TIME NOW = time + 1

 Beep

 Loop
```

**EDIT**

Working Answer:

The Script for your Macro, can have it as a separate sub which gets called for repeating the error:

```
Private Sub ErrorBeep()

    'For ensuring the Toggle Button value is False
    UserForm1.ToggleButton1.Value = False

    'Showing UserForm1
    UserForm1.Show
    'Creating the Beep Loop
             'By a ToggleButton you can check the status from your Main Sub or Code
    Do Until UserForm1.ToggleButton1.Value = True

        'Current Time plus 1 second
        Wait1Second = Time + #12:00:01 AM#
        'Do Until current time is greater than the delayed time
        Do Until Wait1Second < Time
            'DoEvents helps the operating system catchup in loops
            DoEvents
            'Checking if the Button has been pressed to avoid a delay between the loops to remove the message
            If UserForm1.ToggleButton1.Value = True Then Exit Do

        Loop
        'Having your beeps
        Beep
    Loop
    'Hiding the UserForm when the Toggle Button have been pressed
    UserForm1.Hide

    'I assume you will want to repeat this Form
    'For next use reset the ToggleButton Value
    UserForm1.ToggleButton1.Value = False
End Sub
```

Have a Userform which with name `UserForm1` with a ToggleButton with name `ToggleButton1`.

Obliviously you can have the names whatever you like, just remember to update the scripting as required.

Comment: Was not sure that it was going work work. Why do you want a beep every few seconds? If you use a warning message box then it will make a sound

Comment: yes but i want the sound to keep playing to get the attention of the user, the user maybe little far away from the pc and he may not hear the beep sound if it is one time only.

Comment: I will post a Userform answer tomorrow

Comment: @HatemHusam have a look at the Edit